# How to include static library on esp32 idf?

Tags: static-libraries, esp32

I am trying to include a static library that I wrote in another project but I couldn't. Is there anyone who knows how to do it on esp32 idf?

Comment: Did you already included the header file and add the .c in the cmakelist.txt?

Comment: None has updates? I am facing the same issue